# Javascript Filter In Custom Controller Not Returning Filtered Results to Visualforce Page

Tags: javascript, custom-controller, filters, aggregateresult

I have a custom controller and page with a few lines of Javascript. The functionality should work as follows: when a user enters a state or account name in the parameters, the list of accounts and their aggregated results should display according to the filters. The list loads fine, and if you enter values in the parameters, the soql query changes as expected, but the list view does not change. What am I doing wrong?

Controller:

```
public with sharing class inspectionsDashboard {

    public List<AggregateResult> Result {get;set;}    
    public List<Summary> SummaryList {get;set;}
    public List<Account> AcctList {get;set;}
    public Map<Id, Account> IdAccount {get;set;}
    List<Id> Ids {get;set;}
    private String soql {get;set;}

    public String sortDir {
        get  { if (sortDir == null) {  sortDir = 'asc'; } return sortDir;  }
        set;
    }

    // the current field to sort by. defaults to last name
    public String sortField {
        get  { if (sortField == null) {sortField = 'Name'; } return sortField;  }
        set;
    }

    // format the soql for display on the visualforce page
    public String debugSoql {
        get { return soql + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir + ' limit 20'; }
        set;
    }

    public void toggleSort() {
        // simply toggle the direction
        sortDir = sortDir.equals('asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
        // run the query again
        runQuery();
    }

    public inspectionsDashboard() {
        SummaryList = new List<Summary>();
        Result = new List<AggregateResult>();
        Ids = new List<Id>();
        AcctList = new List<Account>();
        IdAccount = new Map<Id, Account>();
        soql = 'SELECT Name,BillingState FROM Account WHERE Id IN : Ids';

        Result = [SELECT Count(Id) Total, Sum(Home_Inspection_dollars__c) Dollars, Franchise__c 
                  FROM Inspection__c 
                  WHERE Month_Since_Launch__c > 0 AND Status__c = 'Completed' 
                  GROUP BY Franchise__c];               

        for(AggregateResult a : Result) {   
            Ids.add((Id)a.get('Franchise__c'));
        }

        runQuery();

        System.debug('Account List' + AcctList);

        for(Account a : AcctList) {
            IdAccount.put(a.Id, a);            
        }

        System.debug('Ids and Accounts are ' + IdAccount);

        for(AggregateResult a : Result) {
            Account TempAcct = new Account();            
            TempAcct = IdAccount.get((Id)(a.get('Franchise__c')));
            system.debug('Account Name is ' + TempAcct.Name);
            SummaryList.add(new Summary(a, TempAcct.Name, TempAcct.BillingState));                
        }       
    }

    public void runQuery() {

        try {
          AcctList = Database.query(soql + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir + ' limit 20');
        } catch (Exception e) {
          ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Ooops!'));
        }
    }

    public class Summary {
        public Integer Total {get;set;}
        public Decimal Dollars {get;set;}
        public String AcctName {get;set;}
        public String StateProvince {get;set;}

        public Summary(AggregateResult a, String AccountName, String State) {
            Total =  (Integer)a.get('Total');
            Dollars = (Decimal)a.get('Dollars');
            AcctName = AccountName;
            StateProvince = State;
        }
    }

    public PageReference runSearch() {

        String AccountName = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccountName');
        String State = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('State');
        soql = 'SELECT Name,BillingState FROM Account WHERE Id IN : Ids';

        List<String> li = new List<String>();
        if (!AccountName.equals(''))
          li.add(' Name LIKE \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(AccountName)+'%\'');
        if (!State.equals(''))
          li.add(' BillingState LIKE \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(State)+'%\'');  
        String c = String.join( li, ' or ');
        if (c.length() > 0)
            c = ' and (' + c + ')';
        system.debug('condition: ' + c);
        soql += c;
        // run the query again
        runQuery();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page controller="inspectionsDashboard" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:pageMessages id="errors" />

        <apex:pageBlock title="Find Me A Franchisee!" mode="edit">

          <table width="100%" border="0">
              <tr>  
                <td width="200" valign="top">

            <apex:pageBlock title="Parameters" mode="edit" id="criteria">

              <script type="text/javascript">
              function doSearch() {
                searchServer(
                  document.getElementById("AccountName").value,
                  document.getElementById("State").value
                  );
              }
              </script> 

              <apex:actionFunction name="searchServer" action="{!runSearch}" rerender="results,debug,errors">
                  <apex:param name="AccountName" value="" />
                  <apex:param name="State" value="" />
              </apex:actionFunction>

              <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
              <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Account Name<br/>
                <input type="text" id="AccountName" onkeyup="doSearch();"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">State/Province<br/>
                <input type="text" id="State" onkeyup="doSearch();"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              </table>

              </apex:pageBlock>
              </td>

        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!SummaryList}" var="r"> 
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Account Name" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                            <apex:param name="sortField" value="AccountName" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!r.AcctName}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="State/Province" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                            <apex:param name="sortField" value="State" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!r.StateProvince}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Number of Home Inspections" value="{!r.Total}" id="Total"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Home Inspection $" value="{!r.Dollars}" id="Dollars"/>
            </apex:pageblockTable>

            <apex:pageBlock title="Debug - SOQL" id="debug">
                <apex:outputText value="{!debugSoql}" />           
            </apex:pageBlock>

        </apex:pageBlock>
              </tr>   
           </table>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mark an element as the "results" element, resulting in your table not updating. Simply adding `id="results"` to the page block element where the results are shown should fix your problem.

Comment: You're right. I was missing that id. I added it to the pageblock for the Summary List, but the results are the same